# Android dark mode follow system returns wrong mode unless killing the app

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design, material-components-android

I'm implementing dynamic dark mode change in the app I'm working on and It's working great for `MODE_NIGHT_YES` and for `MODE_NIGHT_NO` but when I'm setting this on `MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM` it does apply the theme but not with the right mode selected by the user in the phone's settings.

I'm setting the theme by calling

```
fun updateThemeSelection(mode: Int) {
    selectedMode = mode // Saving to shared preference to remember user choice
    setDefaultNightMode(mode)
}
```

The way we check if the system is set to dark mode or not is with this function (I tried other configurations as well)

```
fun Configuration.isSystemInDarkMode(): Boolean {
    val defaultNightMode = AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode()

    if (defaultNightMode == AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES) return true
    if (defaultNightMode == AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO) return false

    return (uiMode and Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK) == Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES
}
```

This does work well except for `MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM` that only works after force closing the app in all other cases it returns the last known mode.

The weird thing is that if I set `android:configChanges="uiMode"` on the activity in the manifest `fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration)` is being triggered when I toggle the dark mode quick settings but when running `isSystemInDarkMode()` on the `config` I receive the last known mode until the app is killed...

I even debugged the bits of `uiMode` and `Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK` and they return the last values.

I also tried using `setLocalNightMode(int)` and `applyDayNight()` and I received the same result.

I don't think it's a device-specific bug because I run it both on an emulator and on a OnePlus 7 pro, both running android 11.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using appcompat 1.4.1
downgrade the version fixes it, for now, I still need to investigate more why it is happening

```
const val appcompat = "1.3.1"
const val appcompat = "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:${Versions.appcompat}"
```

there is a bug for it here
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/188681415